# Tricky populate fields of excel sheet based on mapping using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df, df1, that, based on the bound, year, and state, I would like to populate another df, df3, with values from df2 if the year, qtr, state bound, and type match. I am thinking of using a combination of Pandas and OpenPyXL, but still researching this.

**Data**

df1

```
year    state   bound
2027    CA      low_stat
2027    CA      low_re
2027    NY      med_stat
2027    NY      med_re
```

df2

```
year    qtr    state type   low_stat low_re med_stat med_re high_stat   high_re
2027    2027Q1  NY   AA     5        6      0        1      3           4
2027    2027Q1  CA   AA     1        4      5        4      1           4
2027    2027Q2  NY   AA     3        6      4        16     56          1
2027    2027Q2  CA   AA     11       2      3        2      3           2
2027    2027Q1  NY   BB     1        2      3        4      3           2
2027    2027Q1  CA   BB     9        3      2        2      3           2
2027    2027Q2  NY   BB     3        1      4        1      5           6
2027    2027Q2  CA   BB     9        5      2        5      3           2
```

df3

```
year    state    qtr      low_stat_AA low_re_AA low_stat_BB low_re_BB med_stat_AA med_re_AA med_stat_BB med_re_BB
2027    CA       2027Q1                             
2027    CA       2027Q2                             
2027    NY       2027Q1                             
2027    NY       2027Q2
```

**Desired**

```
year    state   qtr     low_stat_AA low_re_AA low_stat_BB low_re_BB med_stat_AA med_re_AA   med_stat_BB med_re_BB
2027    CA      2027Q1  1           4         9           3             
2027    CA      2027Q2  11          2         9           5             
2027    NY      2027Q1                                              0           1            3          4
2027    NY      2027Q2                                              4           16           4          1
```

**Doing**

```
 merged = pd.merge(df2,df3, on = 'year','state','type')
```

I may be able to use a merge. However, I am still researching as this is not specific.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1**

melt `df2` & merge with `df1`

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2.melt(['year', 'qtr', 'state', 'type'], var_name='bound'))
```

`df_merge.head(5)`

```
    year    state   bound       qtr     type    value
0   2027    CA      low_stat    2027Q1  AA      1
1   2027    CA      low_stat    2027Q2  AA      11
2   2027    CA      low_stat    2027Q1  BB      9
3   2027    CA      low_stat    2027Q2  BB      9
4   2027    CA      low_re      2027Q1  AA      4
```

**Step2**

make pivot_table using `df_merge`.
Strings in the `bound` column and the `type` column must be connected with '_', so let's create `grouper` using the str.cat function.

```
grouper = df_merge['bound'].str.cat(df_merge['type'], sep='_')
out = (df_merge
       .pivot_table('value', index=['year', 'state', 'qtr'], columns=grouper)
       .reset_index())
```

`out`

```
bound   year    state   qtr     low_re_AA   low_re_BB   low_stat_AA low_stat_BB med_re_AA   med_re_BB   med_stat_AA med_stat_BB
0       2027    CA      2027Q1  4.0         3.0         1.0         9.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1       2027    CA      2027Q2  2.0         5.0         11.0        9.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2       2027    NY      2027Q1  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0         4.0         0.0         3.0
3       2027    NY      2027Q2  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         16.0        1.0         4.0         4.0
```

If you want the same sorting as `df3`, you can `reindex` it using `df3.columns`.

```
out.reindex(columns=df3.columns)
```